# Error while reading csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a specific comma value from a csv file but i am getting the full row value how can i get the specific comma value

My csv looks like this

```
Index,Time,Energy
1,1.0,45.034
```

i need to get the values of Energy in each column.

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: plz paste your code, your current output or return value, and your expected output here。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
  rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
   print(row['Energy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('file.txt')
f.readline() # To skip header
for line in f:
    print(line.split(',')[2])
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it working even if the position of column Energy changes, you can do this:

```
with open('your_file.csv') as f:
    # Get header
    header = f.readline()
    energy_index = header.index('Energy')
    # Get Energy value
    for line in f.readlines():
        energy = line.split(',')[energy_index]
        # do whatever you want to do with Energy
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. Hoping this is what you are looking for.

```
import csv
try:
    fobj = open(file_name, 'r')
    file_content = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
except:
    fobj.close()
    file_content = False

if file_content:
    for row_data in file_content:
        try:
            # This will return the 3rd columns value i.e 'energy'
            row_data[2] = row_data[2].strip()
            print row_data[2]
        except:
            pass

    fobj.close()
```